# Microsoft JScript Compilation error - Un-terminated String Constant

Tags: javascript, jscript

```
var newpath= workingDir + "Nodelist_" + ".txt";   

iStream=fso.OpenTextFile(newpath, 1, false);
var ss;
ss="";
var sLine = "";

while(!iStream.AtEndOfStream) { 

    sLine = iStream.ReadLine() 
    var res =  sLine.split("\t");
              sLine = res[0]+ "\t" +  res[0]   

            sLine+="\r\n";

    ss = ss + sLine;

 }        


 iStream.Close();
 if(fso.FileExists(newpath))
   fso.DeleteFile(newpath);

varFileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(newpath, 8, true,0);  
varFileObject.write(ss) 
varFileObject.close()
```

Orginal file data is in below fashion:

```
Node Number
2175 
2681
2708
2709
2737
2738
2777
2779
2823
2824
2889
11019
11020
12134
12193
12261
12262
12263
12264
12405
```

This is in one column whole data

I wanted this data to be written in notepad file as

```
Node Number Node Number
2175    2175
2681    2681
2708    2708
2709    2709
2737    2737
2738    2738
2777    2777
2779    2779
2823    2823
2824    2824
2889    2889
11019   11019
11020   11020
12134   12134
12193   12193
12261   12261
12262   12262
12263   12263
12264   12264
12405   12405
```

These are in two columns data.

The above script written works well but I wanted to avoid this command sLine+="\r\n" because it is giving me an error of Microsoft J Script compilation error ( Un-terminated string constant ) in some of machines. I do not why. Anyways I just wanted to know if there can be another way of doing above task?

Comment: Please note, above data is in columns, not in rows as showing on window..

Comment: @ajm, Thanks for fixing format...I did not know how to do it..

Comment: No problem! For future reference, I used code formatting (4 spaces).